# How can I compute higher powers of a large matrix quickly?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, jordan-normal-form

Is there a block matrix technique, assuming that the matrix has a lot of zeroes in it?  I want to compute its nilpotence degree.

Thanks,

(Even with a lot of zeroes in the matrix, there's still a lot of room for error in doing the computations by hand and not by Wolfram, etc., if I computed dot products for *every* entry of the matrix.)

EDIT: I think that, given a *strictly* upper triangular matrix, then its nilpotence degree is easy to find -- every power I raise the matrix to wipes out a non-zero column (from left to right).  But what I am after is the powers of a matrix, since I want to compute the chain of nullspaces, at power =1,2,3, ...,n in order to find cyclic generalized eigenvectors, with the goal of describing the matrix's Jordan form.

Comment: Did you know that you can compute $a^n$ using around $\log_2(n)$ multiplications by a divide-and-conquer algorithm? Do you need to do better than that?

Comment: Matlab handles sparse matrix multiplication, as does mathematica.

Comment: Hi @RobArthan, can is there an online resource that describes this algorithm?  I will check Wikipedia now.  Thanks,

Comment: Hi @Omnomnomnom, unfortunately I can't use either of those applications, since I am preparing for exams and would have to compute the matrices by hand :(  so far, the worst I've seen are 15x15 matrices on past exams.

Comment: If it's an exam question, it's probably best you post the individual questions.  I'm sure that there are a handful of "tricks" that work for the matrices in question.

Comment: My guess is that a little knowledge about [Kronecker products](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product) might go a long way, especially if there is a block-matrix structure.

Comment: My comment was a generic one about calculating powers in a ring and not specific to matrix multiplication: all you do is recursively compute $a^{2n}$ as $a^n\times a^n$ and $a^{2n+1}$ as $a^n\times a^n \times a$ (and do the obvious thing for $a^0$ and $a^1$).

Comment: Hi @Omnomnomnom, ok I will ask a separate question later tonight and give an example matrix.  Thanks so much.

Comment: Thanks so much, @RobArthan.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $A$ is a sparse matrix then to compute $Av$ is not expensive. So we may just take a random vector $v_1$ and compute $A^k v_1$ till we get zero. That gives a lower bound on the nilpotence degree of $A$. Then, we may restrict $A$ to the complement of $\text{Span}(v_1,Av_1,\ldots,A^{k_1} v_1)$ and keep running the same procedure till the complement of $\text{Span}(v_1,\ldots,A^{k_1}v_1,\ldots,v_m,\ldots,A^{k_m}v_m)$ has dimension less than $\max(k_1,\ldots,k_m)$. That maximum is the nilpotence degree.

For short, me may use a [Krylov-subspace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krylov_subspace) attack that is very effective against sparse matrices.

Comment: Interesting answer, @JackD'Aurizio -- it sounds like you are *already* carving out cyclic subspaces at the same time that you are computing the nilpotence degree of the matrix A.  Am I interpreting your answer correctly?  Thanks,

Comment: @LebronJames: yes, that is exactly the point.

Comment: Thanks so much @JackD'Aurizio - very cool algorithm.

Comment: Hi @Jack D'Aurizio, can I ask you one more follow-up question regarding your answer?  Say dim(V) = 5, and using the algorithm you described, I pick a random vector and find that I have to apply A to it 3 times before it gets killed.  This gives a cyclic subspace of dimension = 3.  I then find another random vector, making sure it is independent of the first random vector, and then notice that I need to apply A to it twice before it gets killed.  This gives me a cyclic subspace of dimension=2, and by the linear independence of the cyclic spaces, we now have a factorization of V, since dimV=5.

Comment: And there is no need to iterate the process after this step.  We've found a Jordan basis, *and* the nilpotence degree at the same time.  So, we've avoided computing matrix powers entirely and avoided computing the chains of nullspaces, and the generalized eigenvectors that span each higher-level nullspace entirely -- and instead just look at iterations of the much-easier A(v).  And we can then read off the number and sizes of Jordan blocks of this nilpotent matrix.  Do I have it right?  Thanks,

Comment: A little wordy, but I just want to be sure - thanks so much :-)

Comment: @LebronJames: if you find a cyclic subspace of dimension $3$ for a $5\times 5$ matrix then you are done, the nilpotence degree is $3$, since it can't be bigger: $5-3=2<3$.

Comment: Ahhh..of course.  Thanks so much, @Jack D'Aurizio!  Have a great night :-)